# Dojo Dijit MenuBar

Tags: css, dojo, widget

My question is actually two.
The first is if it’s possible to maintain the state of the menu on click, i.e., I don’t want to have the first level of the menu closed after a sub menu item its clicked but only when click it again.

The second is that i am trying to find the CSS class that changes the background color of the first level of the menu bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to change the CSS definition but you can change the background using code like:

```
  pMenuBar = new dijit.MenuBar({
     style: "width: 100%;height: 30px;margin-left:2px;margin-top:0px;color:#f5f7f7;font-size: 13px;background-color: transparent;"
  });
```

If not transparent supply your own color....